# What can i use instead "presentModalViewController"?

Tags: ios

I wanna take photo from my code. So here is my code that calls camera:

```
 [self presentModalViewController:self.cameraViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES];
```

But when it works my parent view's `dealloc` function works. So I need this view information. Is there anyway that I can use instead of `presentModalViewController`? Or any other way to seolve this issue. Thanks.

EDIT:
my .h class

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)CameraViewController_iPhone *cameraViewController;
```

my .m class

```
-(void)openCamera{

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    [self.cameraViewController setupImagePicker:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    self.cameraViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    self.cameraViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

    [self presentModalViewController:self.cameraViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES];
}
```

}

Comment: Is the property (self.cameraViewController) qualified as being "strong"?

Comment: I don't understand. Why would you not want to present it as a Modal. Do you want it shown through a Navigation Controller? Other than those two kinds of showing a view, you could only overwrite the superview. I have no idea why you would want to do that.

Comment: @AceLegend, His actual question is something else. Dont just go by the title. His problem is that the parent view is getting deallocated when he show this screen.

Comment: @Till Yes, cameraViewController is strong.

Comment: @yatanadam that does not make sense. Show us the part that assigns the instance of the CameraViewController to that property.

Comment: @Till take a look my edit pls.I added more code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to present the camera as a modal view controller.

Edit: Then you have a basic memory management problem.  It is best to learn to program without ARC.  You should only use it after you understand memory management in objective-c.

Comment: its not a modal.It was pushed to navigationController.

Comment: @yatanadam Edited answer in response to comment.

Comment: Are you saying that it was impossible to show a viewController modally on top of an already modally displayed viewController?

Comment: Ok@AdamLockhart. Thanks for answer.But do you have any idea how i can solve issue?